# SQLite Delete statement with 2 inner joins

Tags: sqlite, inner-join, sql-delete

Why am I getting an error with this statement?

```
Error: could not prepare statement (1 near "t3": syntax error)
```

(Note: tables renamed for simplicity)

```
DELETE FROM table3 t3
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.tempId = t3.tempId 
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.tempId = t2.tempId
WHERE t1.tempId = 9;
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*"Heh ..."* I don't think that the `DELETE` statement knows *anything* about "joins" ...

... and I sure-as-heck think that I understand *why (not)."

*Instead, do this:*

- Start a transaction.
- Run a `SELECT` query to obtain a list of record-IDs that meet your
  selection criteria.
- *"Aww, heck ..."* Go ahead and dump a list of those record-IDs to some log-file somewhere ....
- Execute a series of `DELETE` queries to delete these IDs.
- `COMMIT`. *(Or, if anything-at-all goes wrong, `ROLLBACK`.)*

Comment: Balls. I was trying to avoid exactly this!  Thanks.

Comment: Yup ... *"don't try too hard ..."*  **:-D**  Soon enough, your "cleverness" will wind around to bite you in the ... *ahh,* nevermind ...